# "Device name already in use" when trying to access NAS still waking up from sleep

Tags: network-shares, nas, synology, timeout, network-drive

*Environment: windows 10 PC + Synology NAS on a static IP set up to go to sleep after 30m of not using it*

Whenever I try to access a network share mapped to a drive letter, e.g. "V:" in this example I get a "The local device name is already in use" error when the NAS is "asleep".

[image: "The local device name is already in use"]

If I select/click on the drive without actually opening it and wait for ~30s I can access them normally - Windows apparently sends out a signal to wake them up. If I don't do this before actually opening it, I get the error above. (usually after waiting for some time, so there seems to be a timeout while windows waits for them to respond)

I tried various workarounds described online, some of them on this very site and none of them work:

- restarting the "Browser"/"Computer Browser" services
- trying to access via `\\PATH`

The only solution that seems to be working is to kill `explorer.exe` from task manager, and restart it.

I'm either looking for a way to increase this timeout to a minute, or a way to restore the connection without killing explorer.exe/remapping.

Comment: did you ever resolve this? I have exactly the same issue?

Comment: nope, still no clue how to solve this :(

Comment: I may have had a bit of luck with it. I changed the power settings on the NASs in Control Panel (Advance settings) -> Hardware & Power -> HDD Hibernation. I also went into Device Manager on my PC and Properties of my ethernet Network Adapter and changed the Properties -> Power Management and removed "Allow computer to turn off this device". Worth a try?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error. My issue was that my NAS was losing `QuickConnect` access whenever I was using my VPN.

If you disable the VPN it should work as normal.

Comment: Sadly I'm not using a VPN so this is not the cause of my issue :(